# O meu Upload de arquivos em PHP não funciona

Tags: php, arquivo, upload

A mensagem "Erro, não foi possível fazer o upload" é exibida e o upload não é feito.

```
<html>
<body>

<?php

ini_set('display_erros', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

if(isset($_POST['enviar-formulario'])):
    $formatosPermitidos = array("png", "jpeg", "jpg", "gif");
    $extensao = pathinfo($_FILES['arquivo']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    if (in_array($extensao, $formatosPermitidos)):
        $pasta = "arquivos/";
        $temporario = $_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'];
        $novoNome = uniqid().".$extensao";

        if(move_uploaded_file($temporario, $pasta.$novoNome)):
            $mensagem = "Upload feito com sucesso!";
        else:
            $mensagem = "Erro, não foi possivel fazer o upload";

        endif;
    else:
        $mensagem = "Formato invalido";

    endif;

    echo $mensagem;

endif;

?>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="arquivo"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="enviar-formulario">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Esse acima é o meu código.

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Eu mesmo obtive a resposta!

Acontece que eu executo o Linux Mint em meu computador, além dele uso o Lampp para criação do servidor local.

No meu caso eu precisei ir ao Terminal e utilizar o seguinte código:

***sudo chmod o+rwx arquivos***

Onde no lugar de ***arquivos*** eu coloquei o caminho da pasta onde queria que o upload fosse feito. Esse comando altera as permissões de gravação da pasta.